# Рандомный фон GD php

Tags: php, gd

Так работает, черный фон, белые буквы.

```
<?
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(128,128);
    $fon = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $fon);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
?>
```

Создаю массив со цветами и выбираю рандомно цвет.

```
<?
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(128,128);
    $bc = array('0, 0, 0','65, 105, 225','255, 0, 0','0, 128, 128','0, 191, 255','255, 69, 0','124, 252, 0');
    $fon = imagecolorallocate($im, $bc[mt_rand(1,8)-1]);
    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $fon);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
?>
```

echo $bc[0]; существует, что не так?:(

Comment: потому что ты передаешь строку и получается `imagecolorallocate($im, "0, 0, 0");`
а от тебя жду `imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что во втором примере, который вы оставили,в функцию `imagecolorallocate` требуется передавать 4 параметра, а выбором случайного элемента вы передаете всего два.

```
$exp = explode(',', $bc[array_rand($bc)]);
$fon = imagecolorallocate($im, $exp[0], $exp[1], $exp[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(128,128);
$bc = array(
    array(0, 0, 0),
    array(65, 105, 225)
);
$random = $bc[mt_rand(1,8)-1];

array_unshift($random, $im);
$fon = imagecolorallocate($random);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $fon);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
?>
не уверен работает ли) но как вариант
```